# Dynamically generate buttons with loop php

Tags: php, mysql

What I wan't to do is create buttons that are automatically generated from the database. So when I add a new record in the database the button is created Is this possible with a loop? So yes how do I create the button.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Iamthebest1009";
$dbname = "dktp";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM theme";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "". $row["theme_name"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "no results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you need to echo html

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Iamthebest1009";
    $dbname = "dktp";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM theme";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $your_url ="https://www.google.com";
            echo "". $row["theme_name"].  "<br>";
            echo '<a href="'.$your_url.'"><input type="button" name="' .  $row["theme_name"]. '" value="'. $row["theme_name"].'"></a>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "no results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: The `theme_name` isn't shown inside the button but right next to it. And where inside `echo "". $row["theme_name"].  "<br>";
            echo '<input type="button" name="' . $row["theme_name"]. '" >';` do I put the href

Comment: It works, maybe you can help me with the next step. When the button is clicked you need to be redirected to a page where the database rows are shown that have the id of the selected button

Comment: First you need to fetch the id of database. then change $your_url like this
$your_url= "Your_page_link?id=".$row['id']; and please accept this answer if it works for you.

Comment: Right know I use a `SELECT` statement: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Norm LEFT JOIN Org ON norm.org_id = org.id  LEFT JOIN Cluster ON norm.cluster_id = cluster.id LEFT JOIN Orden ON norm.orden_id = orden.id LEFT JOIN Users ON norm.user_id = users.id WHERE theme_id = ".intval($_REQUEST['id'])." ORDER BY orden_id IS NULL DESC";` It needs to be selected on the `theme_id` but it's not working

Comment: It's hard to presume what's wrong with the query unless seeing your database structure

Comment: I have a table norm with `theme_id` as a foreign key. So when you click on a button and let's say the `theme_id` is 1 then you only see the content with `theme_id` 1

Comment: @ARRAHNDRXX You need to create a page for example  theme_details. pass in href="theme_details.php?id=".$id then go to theme_details id query database like "SELECT * FROM theme where id =".$_GET['id'];
and display page according to it. lastly you need to learn CRUD operation in php

Comment: I already have that page. But something in my query isn't right. And It doesnt need to be selected from theme. But from another table and than where theme_id = "Selected from the button"